# Bitcoind, Multisig, and the default account ""

Tags: bitcoind, raw-transaction, bitcoin-core-accounts

I've been attempting to do transactions to and from a multisig address for a couple of days, but I'm finding that my default account "" keeps paying for things, even though I'm explicitly saying other accounts should pay for things via the txid field in createrawtransaction.

For a quick example, if I create a transaction like:

```
bitcoind createrawtransaction [{\"txid\":\"504aa16418fbb871d307249448bcecdaa5699872a4d22b84d170ae64a2fe89ca\",\"vout\":0}], {\"2NASaVRks1dFupX1e6y3SK8BomjhvSv7xGh\":50}
```

(It's formatted this way because I'm running this in a windows command prompt at the moment, hope to be able to run linux soon!)

the account associated to the address in the transaction's vout where n=0 is "test", but after I sign and send this raw transaction and check listaccounts, "" is debited 50 instead of "test".

If it helps at all, 2NASaVRks1dFupX1e6y3SK8BomjhvSv7xGh is a 2 of 3 address of which "test" is a part of.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just how bitcoind handles situations where all of the addresses in a (multisig) transaction are associated with accounts in my wallet? And if so, why??

It's also all being done in regtest mode, but I wouldn't expect bitcoind to handle transactions differently in that mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the answer, Gavin Andresen posted it on bitcointalk.org.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=567321

> Transactions send via sendrawtransaction are always debited from the default "" account. Raw transactions and accounts are not designed to work together, use one or the other .
>
> And preferably not accounts: unless somebody steps up and volunteers to make the accounts feature "industrial-strength" (scalable, integrates with whatever back-end database your company is using to track user information, can be robustly backed up, etc) it is very likely it will be deprecated and then dropped.